# When re-inserting into queue - Huffman Code

Tags: huffman-code

Example

```
3  2  5  5  
a  b  c  d
```

Joining first two

```
   5         |  5   5
3     2      |  c   d
a     b      |
```

I have to put the new tree of five into the queue
Am I obligated to put it in the end like this:

```
5  5   5
c  d  / \
      3 2
      a b
```

Or can I put it in the beginning:

```
   5    5  5
  3 2   c  d
  a b
```

Or even in the middle of 'c' and 'd'

Is it my choice or is there a rule?

Answer (score 0):

It's not your choice, the Queue needs to be sorted at all times (by it's number of occurrences and in case of equal number of occurrences by the depth of the tree). So it needs to be inserted where it belongs into the order.

This is needed to pick the sub-trees with the least amount of occurrences and if there is choice the most shallow one of them by simply pop-ing them.

If you simply resort after every insertion (this is inefficient and should not be done) the position obviously doesn't matter.

Comment: How does the order matter, when all entries have an occurrence value of 5 like in the example?

Comment: " in case of equal number of occurrences [sort] by the depth of the tree" you try to generate trees as shallow as possible (to get shorter codes), so you want to process more shallow ones first, since the earlier a tree is processed, the further down on the end-result it will be.  In your case insertion at the end is correct.

Comment: No, the Huffman algorithm has no objective to make the most shallow tree. You can make any choice, and still get an optimal code. _You_ may have an objective to make the shallowest tree, which gives you a way to decide for some (but not all) arbitrary choices you run into when executing the Huffman algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's your choice. Whichever way you will get an optimal Huffman code, even though two resulting codes can be manifestly different.

You can get:

```
a - 00
b - 01
c - 10
d - 11
```

or you can get:

```
a - 111
b - 110
c - 10
d - 0
```

Now if I multiply the number of bits in each symbol times the number of occurrences, I get for the first code: 2*3 + 2*2 + 2*5 + 2*5 = 30 bits. For the second code: 3*3 + 3*2 + 2*5 + 1*5 = 30 bits. So both codes will code the original message to exactly 30 bits.